# Obtener valor de una lista en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito obtener el segundo valor de esta lista

```
['connections-wfs', 'Prueba', 'url=https://test.com/ows/wfs\n']
```

Los datos no siempre son los mismos pero si siempre tendrá la misma cantidad de valores,en este ejemplo seria

> 'Prueba'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener un elemento en una lista solo necesitas el indice (usando base 0):

```
lista = ['connections-wfs', 'Prueba', 'url=https://test.com/ows/wfs\n']

n = lista[1] # Prueba
```

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que tu lista se llame lista1.

```
lista1[1]
```

En las listas, puedes acceder a las posiciones determinadas, esto es lista[0] te sacará el primer valor de la lista, lista[1] el segundo, lista[n] te sacará el valor en la posición n+1 de la lista.